# Each Slide Has Something Missing In Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I created a dynamic image slider in my theme that pulls from a category I named Slider. The images show up fine however each slide has only one piece of information. Right now I have two slides. Each slide has a title and a button being called. But the first slide only has the title and the second slide only has a button. Both posts are correctly set up in the back-end to display both. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php 
 $number = 0; 
 query_posts('category_name=slider'); 
 if(have_posts()):  
?>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">  <?php 
   $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name' => 'Slider', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1 
    )); 
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
   $the_query->the_post();
  ?>
   <div class="item active">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
     <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
    </div>
   </div><!-- item active -->
  <?php 
   endwhile; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
    <?php 
 $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'category_name' => 'Slider', 
  'posts_per_page' => 3, 
  'offset' => 1 
  )); 
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
 $the_query->the_post();
?>
    <div class="item">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="slider-subhead"><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" role="button"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button', true); ?></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <?php 
   endwhile; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```